# print posts in automatic list (pug,mysqlm,node.js,express)

Tags: mysql, node.js, list, express

my code is :

```
app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
  Posts.findAll().then(function(posts){
    res.render(__dirname + "/home.pug", {posts:posts});
  })
```

at node and :

```
div
  each val in posts
    li= val
```

at pug, but it return:[object SequelizeInstance:mensages](mensages is the database name) instead the value

*sorry for my English and if the question is confuse*

Comment: This question doesn't contain any mysql relevant information. Please remove mysql tag from querstion.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong.
You should do it like this:

```
ul
 each val in posts
   li= val
```

Have a look at [pug iterations](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html).